# group pandas series or data frame by dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry if this has been asked before, I did a quick search and didn't see anything.

I have a dataframe:

```
        Density
1212e   0.076014
1212f   0.210480
1212g   0.175493
1212h   0.176658
1212i   0.163813
1212l   0.138801
1212m   0.125144
1212o   0.118789
1212p   0.167668
1212q   0.106552
321aa   0.173623
321dd   0.215807
321ee   0.184621
321l    0.177182
321m    0.162529
321n    0.208383
321o    0.207479
321q    0.200622
321y    0.088065
321z    0.150651
```

and a dictionary:

```
animals = {'5992' :('1212e', '1212f', '1212g', '1212h', '1212i'), 
           '6894' : ('321l', '321m', '321n', '321o', '321p', '321q'),
           '5866' : ('1212l', '1212m', '1212n', '1212o', '1212p', '1212q'), 
           '6137' : ("321aa", '321dd', '321ee', '321y', '321z') }
```

My end goal is to create a multi layer index that uses the keys from animals as the top layer, and the incidences from my dataframe as the second.

something like:

```
                Density
5992    1212e   0.076014
        1212f   0.210480
        1212g   0.175493
        1212h   0.176658
        1212i   0.163813
```

Is there a good pythonic way to do this, I was considering creating a new column, setting it off the index, then setting that new column to the higher index. However that seems a bit roundabout and I would rather learn how to write some cleaner code, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late response, my laptop was stolen last week so I am just getting back to checking on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your `animals` dict and use `df.map`

```
inv_animals = {i: int(k) for k, v in animals.items() for i in v}
```

This gives you a mapping from your `code` to an `animal` number

```
{'1212e': 5992,
 '1212f': 5992,
 '1212g': 5992,
 '1212h': 5992,
 '1212i': 5992,
 '321l': 6894,
 '321m': 6894,
 '321n': 6894,
 '321o': 6894,
 '321p': 6894,
 '321q': 6894,
 '1212l': 5866,
 '1212m': 5866,
 '1212n': 5866,
 '1212o': 5866,
 '1212p': 5866,
 '1212q': 5866,
 '321aa': 6137,
 '321dd': 6137,
 '321ee': 6137,
 '321y': 6137,
 '321z': 6137}
```

Then simply use `df.map` and set your indices

```
df['animal'] = df.code.map(inv_animals)
df.set_index(['animal', 'code'])

               density
animal code
5992   1212e  0.076014
       1212f  0.210480
       1212g  0.175493
       1212h  0.176658
       1212i  0.163813
5866   1212l  0.138801
       1212m  0.125144
       1212o  0.118789
       1212p  0.167668
       1212q  0.106552
6137   321aa  0.173623
       321dd  0.215807
       321ee  0.184621
6894   321l   0.177182
       321m   0.162529
       321n   0.208383
       321o   0.207479
       321q   0.200622
6137   321y   0.088065
       321z   0.150651
```

Answer (score 0):

an approach using a join with a multiindex:

```
dict = {'Density': {'1212e': 0.076014,'1212f': 0.210480,
      '1212g': 0.175493,'1212h': 0.176658,'1212i': 0.163813,'1212l': 0.138801,'1212m': 0.125144,'1212o': 0.118789,'1212p': 0.167668,
      '1212q': 0.106552,'321aa': 0.173623,'321dd': 0.215807,
      '321ee': 0.184621,'321l': 0.177182,'321m': 0.162529,'321n': 0.208383,
      '321o': 0.207479,'321q': 0.200622,'321y': 0.088065,'321z': 0.150651}}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df1.index.name = 'id'
animals = {'5992' :('1212e', '1212f', '1212g', '1212h', '1212i'), 
           '6894' : ('321l', '321m', '321n', '321o', '321p', '321q'),
           '5866' : ('1212l', '1212m', '1212n', '1212o', '1212p', '1212q'), 
           '6137' : ("321aa", '321dd', '321ee', '321y', '321z') }
l = []
for k,v in  animals.iteritems():
     l.extend (pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[k],v]))

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(l)
idx.names = ['key','id']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = idx)

df2.join(df1)




                Density
key     id  
5866    1212l   0.138801
        1212m   0.125144
        1212n   NaN
        1212o   0.118789
        1212p   0.167668
        1212q   0.106552
6894    321l    0.177182
        321m    0.162529
        321n    0.208383
        321o    0.207479
        321p    NaN
        321q    0.200622
6137    321aa   0.173623
        321dd   0.215807
        321ee   0.184621
        321y    0.088065
        321z    0.150651
5992    1212e   0.076014
        1212f   0.210480
        1212g   0.175493
        1212h   0.176658
        1212i   0.163813
```